# Safari audio delay while playing mp3

Tags: audio, safari

On button hover or click short mp3 audio should be played (less then 1 sec).

This code used to play audio:

```
<audio id="hover-sound" src="/assets/hover-sound.mp3"></audio>

$('#hover-sound')[0].currentTime = 0
$('#hover-sound')[0].play()
```

It works in both Chrome and Safari, but it is slightly delayed in Safari (200-300 ms).

Please advice is there a way to remove Safari delay?

Thanks.